# C# and PHP encryption/decryption php problem with keysize

Tags: c#, php, cryptography

**The issue is why does a 32 character string work in C# .NET but not in php mcrypt, and how to make them compatible? (I have a method of doing it with AES, 3DES remains open.**

I'm trying to create a cryptography api which uses Microsofts Crypto Api's in .NET and PHP's mcrypt to encrypt and decrypt data.

C# should be able to encrypt and decrypt, the PhP only needs to decrypt. The problem is I would like the user to be able to define their own key. To do this, I have md5 hashed the password they enter. This works perfectly on the C # side, but in PHP I get

Warning: mcrypt_decrypt() [function.mcrypt-decrypt]: Size of key is too large for this algorithm in C:\xampp\htdocs\failcrypt\crypt.php on line 40

(An empty "" string should work, as well as fairly large keys.

All the links I can find have preset keys, but mine must work for arbitrary key sizes on both sides.

```
        echo $key."</br>";
        echo md5($key)."</br>";
        $newKey = md5($key)."</br>";
        echo strlen($newKey)."</br>";
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, md5($key), base64_decode($msg), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        echo $decrypted;
```

outputs

red (the key)

bda9643ac6601722a28f238714274da4 (the hash)

Comment: Looks like something happens with the key while you transport it. I would smell an encoding issue, however you wrote it's a MD5 hash which should not have obvious encoding issues when transported. How do you pass the key string from c# to PHP?

Comment: @hakre The key can be hardcoded right now, its just that both the php and c# must be able to use the same key

Comment: Hmm, the strlen you give in your question is wrong. I get 32 for the has, not 37. ?

Comment: The strlen you're echoing includes the `<br /`> characters...

Comment: Yea, I didn't notice the </br>, but the question is really how to use the same string (key) on both sides.

Comment: The problem basically is that the php 3des doesn't take 256bit keys, but the php AES does, so I'm switching over and I'll see how that works out

Comment: In any case, simply md5ing the passwords is not secure, it's susceptible to a dictionary attack. Cf. [PKCS#5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127)/Password-based Encryption for details on how to make this secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it, the key size will never be arbitrary. It will always be the output of the MD5 hash. You are using a (weak) form of password based key derivation function (PBKDF). So the key really isn't the string "red", it is the output of the MD5 function.

```
 $ echo red | tr -d [:space:] | openssl dgst
 (stdin)= bda9643ac6601722a28f238714274da4

 $ echo The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. | tr -d [:space:] | openssl dgst
 (stdin)= 09ecfef50e54940a3d241a10b7e70e3c
```

That being said, mcrypt_decrypt needs raw bytes for the key. Here is working code :

```
 $key = "Use any string you want as a password.";
 $encrypted = base64_decode("OcSlUzWMgac5RxYyt+An0g==");  //This is the base64 encoded cipher text

 $newKey = hash("md5", $key, TRUE); 
 //echo base64_encode($newKey)."\n";

 $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $newKey, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

 echo $decrypted;
```

You can increase the strength of your PBKDF by adding salt and iterating many times. So instead of using only :

```
md5(password)
```

Use something like

```
md5(salt+md5(salt+md5(salt+md5(salt+md5(salt+password)))))
```

You get the idea. Better yet, use a [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) implementation in C# and PHP that produce the same key.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how I would get both the C# and PHP to work with arbitrary key sizes?

Comment: +1 for PBKDF. See [PKCS#5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127) for details.

Comment: @ixe013 Yea, I get that I'm using the hash, the problem is that the php 3des doesn't want to take the hashed key as input, it says the key is too large.

Comment: The key must be raw bytes. I added working code to my answer.